# Historical BTC data in JSON

Tags: api, json-rpc, ios

As of now, the only API I can find that serves historical data is https://blockchain.info/charts/market-price?timespan=60days&format=json. It only uses USD, and I need to serve non-USD data. My google-fu is failing me, does anyone know of an API that serves historical data for more than one currency? Preferably a currency I can specify as part of the API call.

Comment: I believe Coindesk has an index of data in various currencies. http://www.coindesk.com/price/ What you have to know however is that it was not possible to buy BTC in all currencies from the get-go. USD was the original traded currency, so that has the longest history. You could theoretically derive the price for any given day based on the FOREX rates in OANDA or XE.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Bitcoin Charts API](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Modern answer for visibility: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/
Nice api they having pricing breakdowns for day, hour and minute granularity.

Answer (score 0):

Free:
https://www.kaggle.com/mczielinski/bitcoin-historical-data

Not Free:
This is the most extensive data set you'll find for free.  I augment it with data exported from TradingView.