# Single API to Get Fee Estimates for All Major Cryptocurrencies?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, client, api, altcoin

Many sites provide estimates of miner/gas fees for individual cryptocurrencies. For example, [EtherScan](https://etherscan.io/gastracker) provides gas estimates for ETH. [BTC Network](https://btc.network/estimate) provides fee estimates for Bitcoin.

Both of these sites provide API functionality, but they are limited to a single cryptocurrency. If I wanted to integrate many cryptocurrencies into my site I would need to integrate a different API for each of the cryptocurrencies I support.

I'm looking for a site/solution that offers a single interface to obtain gas/transaction/miner fees for all major coins such as BTC, ETH, LTC, BCH, USDT, USDC, XRP etc. The API must also provide estimates based on the desired transaction confirmation times. In other words, I should be able to request estimated fee if I want 90% likelihood of confirmation within the next 30 min, 60 min, 600 min and so on.

**Update:** Can someone please explain in the comments why this is off topic? **1)** this question IS applicable to Bitcoin (questions in which the answer is the same for Bitcoin are on topic) **2)** I am not seeking a product or service review I am asking if such a service exists (it's a factual question) How does this question differ from:

[Historical BTC data in JSON](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/34100/historical-btc-data-in-json)

[API for automatical buying and selling coins in Java](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/101723/78451)

Which asks for a specific service/API..

Comment: That "Historical BTC data in JSON" question is very old, presumably from before service recommendations were made off-topic.

Comment: @PieterWuille What about this one: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100649/any-charts-bots-out-there-for-volumes-going-from-private-unknown-wallets-to-know

Comment: @PieterWuille I interpret "seeking product or service reviews" as a question that  seeks a review of a particular service which is almost always "subjective" and prone to bias/spam, not a question that is  factual in nature (i.e, which website provides service xyz) as this kind of question is not likely to attract spam or  biased responses

Comment: @PieterWuille Also do you know when this rule was added? As I see dozens of questions that would violate this rule according to your definition

Comment: @PieterWuille what about this one: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/101723/78451

Comment: Questions about other cryptocurrencies are on-topic then when the answer is the same as if it were just asked about Bitcoin. E.g. "How does change work in Litecoin?" is equivalent to "How does change work in Bitcoin?".  I would consider this off-topic, because the answer is not the same as if you just ask it about Bitcoin specifically as you are looking for a service that covers a variety of currencies.