# API for automatical buying and selling coins in Java

Tags: api, java, bots

I need to create a simple bot for buying and selling coins and the programming language needs to be `Java` due to some technical specifications.

These are the functions which I need from that `API`:

- `buy(args)`
- `sell(args)`
- `getCurrentPrice(args)`

If you know any `API`-s which are reliable and suitable for `Java`, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much every exchange offers their own APIs for trading.  Take a look at [kraken](https://www.kraken.com/en-us/features/api#add-standard-order).

Comment: I see that they have examples for some other programming languages, but not Java.
Link: https://www.kraken.com/en-us/features/api#example-api-code

But, I suppose that it is also possible to use that API in Java, right?

Comment: Yes, APIs can be used with any language/tech stack as long as you can send out the requests in the format the API will understand.  You can easily build this service using spring boot for example